Syntax highlighting language request: Apex on salesforce.stackexchange.com

Apex is based on familiar Java idioms, such as variable and expression
syntax, block and conditional statement syntax, loop syntax, object
and array notation.

Syntax highlighting for Apex on salesforce.stackexchange.com currently use default
Code Language (used for syntax highlighting): default

From Highlight List of Supported Language Apex is supported by highlightjs-apex package
Right now salesofrce stackexhange community use ```java to highlight Apex code. Would you mind adding apex syntax highlighting, support?

Minor: but this would probably be better asked directly on the salesforce meta, as the moderators there could add the language hint directly to the tag. (This won't work of course when Apex, is not a recognized language in the version StackExchange is using of highlightjs)

@Lino i saw related posting in salesforce meta post but the change that Staff made didn't reflect on apex tag.
